# (400) Bad Request when calling asmx webmethod dynamically

Tags: c#, soap, asmx, dynamic, webrequest

I am getting (400) bad request when I try to get response from the asmx webservice. Till now, I am able to run the service url provided by the user and get all the webmethods in a dropdown. I then create a SOAP message for the selected webmethod. When user clicks Execute button, I am trying to call the webmethod with SOAP message. Here is the c# code:

```
protected void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(txtWSDL.Text));
    req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Accept = "text/xml";
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/" + ddlMethods.SelectedItem.Text);
    StreamWriter stm = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    stm.Write(txtFormattedSoap.Text);
    stm.Flush();
    stm.Close();

    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();  //I get error in this line.
}
```

Please let me know where/what am doing wrong or if I am missing something.